# Як правильно вживати слова "запитати" та "попросити"?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів

Я не впевнений, як вживати

- "запитати"
- "попросити"

Обидва перекладаються на англійське "to ask", але іноді вони використовуються по-різному, і я не знаю точно коли. Наприклад:

> *"Гройсман **запитав** у Балчуна, де той працював останні 5-7 років, на що той відповів, що був головою наглядової ради польської авіакомпанії "ЛОТ" і шефом вантажної польської залізниці."*
>
> [Українська Правда](http://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2017/01/25/7133424/)

та

> *Порошенко **попросив** Бундестаг визнати Голодомор геноцидом*
>
> [Українська Правда](http://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2017/01/30/7133902/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Використовуйте "запитати", коли йдеться про питання (asking a question) і очікується відповідь.

Використовуйте "попросити", коли йдеться про прохання (asking to do something), і очікується дія.

Докладні визначення можна подивитися тут: [запитувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytuvaty), [просити](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosyty)

Comment: Прийняв зміни (бо в цьому випадку вважаю рівнозначними синонімами), але чому?.. http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53407/26518.html Тут же не йдеться про письмове звернення...

Comment: Не варто відмовлятися від українських слів лише через те, що такі слова є в інших мовах :)
Слово "прозьба" (щоправда, через "з") є навіть у словнику Грінченка. (Вимовляється українською воно все одно "прозьба").
Для мене "прохання" це щось більш особисте чи серйозне, а "просьба" - щось більш формальне/нейтральне... Це лише моє особисте сприйняття.
Ну і якщо "просьба" - росіянізм, то "попросити" теж?..

Comment: @bv. Дякую за спробу поліпшити відповідь. І ця зміна сподобалася двом людям, що схвалили її. Я її відхилив з декількох причин. По-перше, мені здається, що моя поточна відповідь легше читається. По-друге, я ніколи не зустрічав, щоб слово "запитати" використовувалося у значенні "порушити питання". Також, можливо, вас зацікавить обговорення: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/98/